# How can I verify that the shadowsocks server is ready?

Tags: java, socks

I set up the shadowsocks server and start it. I directly create a socket to connect to the server by using the following code:

```
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("my.ss_server.ip",ss_server_port);
    socket.setSoTimeout(5 *1000);
    socket.connect(address);

    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();

    //byte[] VER = {0x05, 0x01, 0x00},socks5 protocol
    os.write(VER);
    os.flush();

    byte[] b = new byte[128];
    int a = is.read(b);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String result = bytesToHexString(b, 0, a);
    System.out.println(result);
```

But unfortunately, read time out finally.Can I directly connect to Shadowsocks server by socket? And does somebody know how to create a simple program to verify connection of Shadowsocks server in java?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking about "verifying the shadowsocks server is ready for the client". So we won't talk about things on the server-side.

Here are two methods to verify the server ports from the client:

1. Test the opening port on the server by the command-line tool: `nc`:

   ```
   # -w 5: timeout in 5 seconds
   nc -z -w 5 <ss_server_ip> <user_port>
   ```

   A successful test output looks like this:

   ```
   Connection to <ss_server_ip> port <ss_user_port> [tcp/***] succeeded!
   ```

   otherwise, it outputs nothing and `nc` exits with code 1.

   Be noted: this method tests only if the port is opening, it doesn't make sure the port is for Shadowsocks.
2. Using the Shadowsocks manager API:

   This requires enabling [Shadowsocks manager API](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks/wiki/Manage-Multiple-Users) on the server-side, it only supports the libev and python version.

   Use the following commands to get the alive Shadowsocks port list from the client-side.

   Be noted: the `ss_manager_ip` may not be the same with the `ss_server_ip`, they may be listening on the different IP address, such as the private and public IP address, that depends on your configuration. And the `ss_manager_port` is definitely different from the `ss_user_port`.

   Dislike the method 1, this method is telling you what ports are listening on the server, but it dosen't make sure those ports are accessible from the client.

   ```
   nc -u <ss_manager_ip> <ss_manager_port>
   ping
   ```

   Or use bash if `nc` is not available:

   ```
   exec 3<>/dev/udp/<ss_manager_ip>/<ss_manager_port>
   echo ping >&3
   cat <&3
   ```

   Or use the Python code(2.7), you can easily port it to Java:

   ```
   import socket
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
   s.connect((<ss_manager_ip>, <ss_manager_port>))
   s.send(b'ping')
   s.recv(4096)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I ping the server IP in windows CMD

```
 Open the Windows Run box by pressing the Windows key and the letter R.

    Type CMD and press enter to open the command prompt.

    Type "ping " followed by the IP address to ping.

    Press Control + "C" key at the same time to stop the ping and see the summary statistics.
```

Or if you're like me using Shadowsocks-libev

```
systemctl status shadowsocks-libev.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a docker images and use it to check server availability at the client side.

Main idea: use ss-tunnel to map local port to [www.google.com:80](http://www.google.com:80), then send HTTP request to local port, you will get a valid HTTP response if your ss-server is available.

https://github.com/oylbin/shadowsocks_availability_monitor